# Unity : Casting shadows of anima2d characters

Tags: unity, 2d, shadows

I want to cast shadows of animated 2d character on a level like this :

[image]

The only thing here I want is dynamic shadows for anima2d character as animation progresses.Is there a way of achieving shadows with anima2D characters?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was using 2d sprite sheets before so I simply flipping the sprite and gave it black color. But I don't think I can do the same thing with skeletal based system i.e anima2d.

Comment: Did you try simply drawing a black oval below the characters that resizes itself during animation?